# Как последовательно удалить все объекты класса

Tags: c++, классы, память, delete

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;



class tovar
{
private:
    static int count;
    int id;
protected:
    char *name;
    int price;
    char* company;
public:
    tovar();
    int get_price() { return price; }
     ~tovar();
    void out();
};
int tovar::count = 0;
tovar::tovar()
{
    char s1[45];
    char s2[45];
    count++;
    id = count;
    cout << "Введите наименование товара ";
    cin >> s1;
    name = new char[strlen(s1)];
    strcpy(name, s1);
    cout << "Цена: ";
    cin >> price;
    cout << "Введите наименование производителя ";
    cin >> s2;
    company = new char[strlen(s2)];
    strcpy(company, s2);
}
tovar::~tovar()
{
    cout << "Удален объект " << id << "." << name;
}
void tovar::out()
{
    cout << id << ". " << name << " " << price << " " << company;
}
class milk :public tovar
{
protected:
    static int count;
    int id;
    int shelf_life;
    int volume;
public:
    milk();
     ~milk();
    void out();
    void swap(milk *);
};
int milk::count = 0;
milk::milk() : tovar()
{
    count++;
    id = count;
    cout << "Введите срок хранения молока в днях: ";
    cin >> shelf_life;
    cout << "Введите объем молока: ";
    cin >> volume;
}

milk::~milk()
{
    cout << "\nУдален объект " << id << "." << name << " сроком хранения " << shelf_life;

}
void milk::out() {
    cout << id << ". " << name << " " << price << " " << company << " " << shelf_life;

}
int vvod()
{
    cout << "Введите кол-во записей: ";
    int z;
    cin >> z;
    return z;
}
void milk::swap(milk *obj)
{
    int temp = obj->id;
    obj->id = id;
    id = temp;

    temp = obj->price;
    obj->price = price;
    price = temp;

    temp = obj->shelf_life;
    obj->shelf_life = shelf_life;
    shelf_life = temp;

    temp = obj->volume;
    obj->volume = volume;
    volume = temp;

    char *h = obj->name;
    obj->name = name;
    name = h;

    char *t = obj->company;
    obj->company = company;
    company = t;
}
void sort(milk *b, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (b[i].get_price() > b[j].get_price())
                b[i].swap(&b[j]);
        }
}
void main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");
    int a = vvod();
    milk *arr = new milk[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        arr[i].out();
    cout << "\n Cортировка: ";
    sort(arr, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        arr[i].out();

    cout << "\nУдаление";
    delete [] arr;
    cout << "\n\nПроверка того,что удалилось:";
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        arr[i].out();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

Есть вот такой код, как сделать так, чтобы объекты класса удалились, через

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        delete arr[i];
```

Не удаляется.

Comment: А так делать не надо, ведь в массиве лежат экземпляры этих объектов, а не указатели на них.

Comment: Можете направить меня, а-то у меня совсем идей нет как это сделать?

Comment: А делать ничего не надо, все объекты и так последовательно удаляются при вызове `delete [] arr;`. А ваша "*Проверка того,что удалилось*" вызывает неопределенное поведение, так как происходит обращение к элементам только что удаленного массива. В С++ отсутствует способ написания кода, который проверял бы, удалилось что-то или нет или является ли указатель / ссылка валидным или нет.

Comment: Cпасибо, как тогда проверит, что удаление прошло правильно?

Comment: Я же уже написал, что никак. После вызова `delete [] arr;` этот указатель становится невалидным и все...

Comment: Понял-принял, невнимательно прочитал, извините.

Comment: Извините, у меня тут сформировался еще один вопросик, а можно ли, например, удалить какой-то один объект класса, а другие оставить нетронутыми?

Comment: если подразумевается "один объект из массива" - то нет